# Accent problems : charset / utf-8 / thelounge IRC

Tags: thelounge

I have a problem with using the IRC client The Lounge.
The type accents : " é à ... " is displayed correctly from the client,
but when a user uses accents from another client accents are no longer displayed on The Lounge is are replaced with " ? " ( see screen )

[image]